# Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working on going through "Head First Design Patterns" and I am trying to properly convert the Java code into C#. Here is what I have. Can you tell me if this is a good implementation/conversion so far?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Duck
{
    public abstract class Duck
    {
        public FlyBehavior flyBehavior;
        public QuackBehavior quackBehavior;
        public Duck(){

        }

        public abstract void display();

        public void performFly()
        {
            flyBehavior.fly();
        }

        public void performQuack()
        {
            quackBehavior.quack();
        }

        public void swim()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All ducks float, even decoys!");
        }
    }

    public interface FlyBehavior
    {
        void fly();
    }

    public class FlyWithWings : FlyBehavior
    {
        public void fly()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm flying!");
        }
    }

    public class FlyNoWay : FlyBehavior
    {
        public void fly()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I can't fly!");
        }
    }

    public interface QuackBehavior
    {
        void quack();
    }

    public class Quack : QuackBehavior
    {
        public void quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quack");
        }
    }

    public class MuteQuack : QuackBehavior
    {
        public void quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<<  Silence  >>");
        }
    }

    public class Squeak : QuackBehavior
    {
        public void quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Squeak");
        }
    }

    public class MallardDuck : Duck
    {
        public MallardDuck()
        {
            quackBehavior = new Quack();
            flyBehavior = new FlyWithWings();
        }

        public override void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm a real Mallard duck");
        }
    }

    public class MiniDuckSimulator
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Duck mallard = new MallardDuck();
            mallard.performQuack();
            mallard.performFly();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public` fields are a bit of a no-no since that violates encapsulation. So I've changed the fields to `private readonly` and inject those dependencies via the constructor. Speaking of constructor, I made it `protected` as a `public` constructor on an `abstract` class doesn't make much sense. Also, make note of C# naming conventions which PascalCase's methods and that `interface`s should start with "`I`":

```
using System;

namespace Duck
{
    public abstract class Duck
    {
        private readonly IFlyBehavior flyBehavior;
        private readonly IQuackBehavior quackBehavior;
        protected Duck(IFlyBehavior flyBehavior, IQuackBehavior quackBehavior)
        {
            this.flyBehavior = flyBehavior;
            this.quackBehavior = quackBehavior;
        }

        public abstract void Display();

        public void PerformFly()
        {
            this.flyBehavior.Fly();
        }

        public void PerformQuack()
        {
            this.quackBehavior.Quack();
        }

        public void Swim()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All ducks float, even decoys!");
        }
    }

    public interface IFlyBehavior
    {
        void Fly();
    }

    public class FlyWithWings : IFlyBehavior
    {
        public void Fly()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm flying!");
        }
    }

    public class FlyNoWay : IFlyBehavior
    {
        public void Fly()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I can't fly!");
        }
    }

    public interface IQuackBehavior
    {
        void Quack();
    }

    public class Quack : IQuackBehavior
    {
        public void Quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quack");
        }
    }

    public class MuteQuack : IQuackBehavior
    {
        public void Quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<<  Silence  >>");
        }
    }

    public class Squeak : IQuackBehavior
    {
        public void Quack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Squeak");
        }
    }

    public class MallardDuck : Duck
    {
        public MallardDuck() : base(new FlyWithWings(), new Quack())
        {
        }

        public override void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm a real Mallard duck");
        }
    }

    public class MiniDuckSimulator
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Duck mallard = new MallardDuck();
            mallard.PerformQuack();
            mallard.PerformFly();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I am going to look over both your answers, but I really appreciate that you took the time to explain in such depth. I am working hard to learn these design patterns and input like this is going to just speed up the process.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that if this was a production application each class would be its own file, but since this is just to learn a strategy pattern in C# I have kept them all in the same file. The changes made by Jesse are perfect and make the code cleaner and safer, so thanks for that. I am studying it will get back to you guys if I have any questions. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, in the Microsoft C# world, `PascalCasing` (as opposed to `camelCasing`) doesn't just apply to classes, but also to public fields, public methods, and public properties.

So maybe you might want to rename `Duck.flyBehavior` to `Duck.FlyBehavior`, `Duck.quackBehavior` to `Duck.QuackBehavior`, etc.

While you're at it, since those are public fields, you might also want to switch those to C# properties, instead, in case you ever needed the added functionality of sanitizing input.

**before**

`public FlyBehavior FlyBahavior`

**after***

`public FlyBehavior FlyBehavior { get; set; }`

Although, I still write C# the old school way, but if things haven't changed, I think interfaces still are prefixed with a capital `I`. So your `FlyBehavior` interface will be named `IFlyBehavior`. Same thing for `QuackBehavior`; it will become `IQuackBehavior`.

Another pedantic remark: although I have a hunch that you already know this, but classes should be in their own file*. I'm just saying, in case my hunch was wrong, and you didn't know.

* Disclaimer: I'm not exactly sure why separating classes into files is considered important. And I am in no way saying that it isn't important, just that if you want to know why, I'm afraid I can only give you my own intuition as to why I *think* it's important to separate classes into their own file.

Comment: "Disclaimer: I'm not exactly sure why separating classes into files is considered important."  Pretty certain it's purely organisational - it's easier to find `public abstract class Duck` when the file is called `Duck.cs` rather than if everything is in `MyProgram.cs`, or separated into `Stuff1.cs`, `Stuff2.cs` etc - easier to find the file *and* easier to find the location in the file where the class starts (the beginning). Edit: I think in Java each class *has to* be a separate file due to the way the compiler works (it expects `Duck.java` to contain `Duck`). Might be wrong on that though.

Comment: Although I personally employ an amount of flexibility in C# - if I've got small, related classes, I'll often dump them into the same file because they'll still be easy to find - in this case, I'd stick `FlyBehaivour` and its implementations in the same file because they're so small and tightly related.